# How to save an image and its path and then use it later to upload using swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, s3transfermanager

I have an app which stores receipts. The way it works is, You save an image using the app and then you upload it to amazon s3 bucket. To upload to amazon s3, you need its local path.

So here is what I'm doing.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
         receiptImageView.image = image
        Model.sharedModel.currentImage = image
        print(info)
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    //MAking the localpath of the image
    let imageAWSName = "ios_" + NSUUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageAWSName)
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localPath!.path) {
        do {
            try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)?.write(to: localPath!)
            Model.sharedModel.currentlocalpath = localPath
            print("file saved")
        }catch {
            print("Error saving receipt photo local path")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Error - localpath already exists")
    }
```

The path looks like this -

```
file:///Users/Al/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FE04FF78-914B-4224-A84B-D10521E0F845/data/Containers/Data/Application/115C6A1B-E61F-4082-AA59-4674D87DF31E/Documents/ios_5AB04F97-32C9-441E-97C8-44D4D2725ADD.jpg
```

Now this works if upload the receipt straight away to s3 bucket. But if I close the app, and then reload it doesn't work.

I think it's because FE04FF78 gets changed everytime you run the app. 
If that's the case how do I get the path of the image?

Comment: you should only save filename and fetch the document path everytime , whenever you need and append to your filename

Comment: because document directory changes everytime you start a new instance of app]

Comment: @UsamaSadiq If you wanna post that as an answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks that helped me out

Comment: Sure thanks, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should only save filename and fetch the document path everytime , whenever you need and append to your filename

Because document path changes every time, whenever a new instance of app launches

Answer (score 0):

You should only save your file name or any sub-folder under `Documents` if needed. If you just open the app from your device then it should work fine. However, every time your app compiles (you debug/run the app from Xcode), the UUID, in this case `FE04FF78-914B-4224-A84B-D10521E0F845`, will change.